# C# 4 Optional Null EventHandler

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, parameters, event-handling, arguments

I am attempting to write a method that has an optional EventHandler Paramater. it currently looks like this:

```
public void AddItemToMainMenu(MenuItem parentMenu, MenuItems item, String menuItemText, bool isChecked, EventHandler? eventHandler = null)
```

the error occurs on the last argument, it states:

> Error 51  The type 'System.EventHandler' must be a non-nullable value
>    type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>    'System.Nullable'

EDIT: I have removed the ? and now receive a very similar error, I also made an unimportant change to another argument. it now reads as follows:

```
 public void AddItemToMainMenu( MenuItems item, String menuItemText, bool isChecked, EventHandler eventHandler = null, MenuItem? parentMenu = null)
```

> Error  41  The type 'System.EventHandler' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make `EventHandler` nullable. Remove the `?` in the definition.

The exception says *`System.EventHandler` must be a non-nullable value type*. Since `EventHandler` is a class, or reference type, it obviously cannot be a value type and is, by convention nullable.

Answer (score 3):

EventHandler is a reference type, therefore is inherently nullable. 
Should be:

```
public void AddItemToMainMenu(MenuItem parentMenu, MenuItems item, String menuItemText, bool isChecked, EventHandler eventHandler = null)
```